# System startup error in Windows 7

Tags: hardware-failure

Lot of times i start the system it does not started thus time mouse and keyboard has no power.

After sometimes it will started to faced the following issue in system startup in windows 7:

```
502M Extended RAM Passed
1024K Cache SRAM Passed
System BIOS shadowed
Video BIOS shadowed
Fixed Disk 0: ST500DM002-1BD142
ATAPI CD-ROM: TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-222BB
Mouse initialized
Error
0662 : Configuration Change has occured
ERROR
0162 : Configuration Error - Default configuration used
Error
0162 : Configuration Error - Default configuration used
```

Comment: "Lot of times i start the system it does not started" - This indicates a hardware problem with a far more evolved solution then simply changing the CMOS battery.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've provided, that's your motherboard BIOS showing you those errors, not Windows.

The first thing to do is try resetting your BIOS to factory defaults and save them.  You should be able to do this from within your BIOS' setup.

If that doesn't help (same errors at next power-on) then the next thing to try is removing and replacing the CMOS battery on your motherboard, and then reset the BIOS settings back to factory defaults.

If that doesn't help, do it again, only use a new/known-good replacement CMOS battery.

If, after that, you still get the same errors but can still boot the system, try (re)flashing the BIOS with the latest version offered by the manufacturer of your motherboard for your model of motherboard.

If you still have errors after that, then you most likely have a faulty motherboard that will need to be replaced.

Comment: I actually would in general just reset the settings even before the battery is changed that might be enough.

Comment: @Ramhound True enough, I considered that, but figured replacing the CMOS battery counted as a pretty through reset. ;) I'll add a basic reset option...